# "To change the sense" vs "to alter the meaning"

Tags: sentence-meaning

A. Your modification changes the sense of the sentence.
B. Your modification alters the meaning of the sentence.

What is the difference?

Comment: Not much, but the second may connote a more drastic change.

Comment: At the level of that Question there is no difference.

Comment: It looks like deciphering a cord to me...

Comment: Not much, but the second may connote a less drastic change.

Answer (score -1):

The former one: Sense depends on situation and timing in which u r using the sentence. U can change the sense by using the same sentence in different contexts. 
These are dynamic.( the same sentence can be taken in different senses by different persons.) eg. Double meaning sentences.

And the latter : U can change the meaning of the sentence mostly by changing the words which are used in it. 
These are static.( Mostly everyone will get similar meaning)